# Google Load Balancers doesn't appear in Monitoring Dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-load-balancer

I created a global load balancer with backend service and enabled the logging in Google Cloud project. The Load Balancer charts and metrics is supposed to appear in Monitoring dashboard, however, the charts and metrics were not be created.

In [the Google Cloud document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#viewing_dashboards), it looks like that if a load balancer exists in the project, the load balancer dashboard is ready to use. I also cannot find to create Load Balancers dashboard manually.

Comment: What kind of LB do you use ? L4, L7 ? Can you provide some more details ?

Answer (score 0):

Go into Monitoring > [Dashboards](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/dashboards) and create a new dasboard. The go [Metrics explorer](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/metrics-explorer) and type into `Find resource type and metric` field `load balancer` and then select your balancer type (HTTP, TCP or UDP). The select metric (for example `utilisation` for HTTP. Then choose filtering option (in my case it was `backend service name`) - it should pop up on the list.

After that you can `save chart` in the dasboard you created. Open this dasboard and you should have a working panel. You can add more charts to observe various metrics.

This solution may vary in case of TCP load balancer (different metrics) but generally that is the way you do it.

I cold provide more specific solution but you have to update your question with more detailes (LB type is the most important).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My load balancer type is HTTPS.
It can solve my question by creating dashboard manually. However, if I have multiple load balancers, it makes me create multiple dashboards. I'm curious about why Google Cloud Platform doesn't create automatically. Because, in my other projects, the dashbaords are generated automatically.

Comment: If you provided some screenshot or more details about the dashboards you're referring to I might be able to say more...